# How to Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Firebase Account?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am unable to to sucessfully to do , I followed the following steps as instructed on Firebase Docs:

1. Signed in use using existing auth provider(**my case:facebook**).
2. Complete the sign-in flow for the new authentication provider up to, but not including, calling one of the `Auth.signInWith` methods.(**my case: i want to link email & password and Google OAUth**).  So this is the step i'm unclear about, I created a new provider using `var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();`  and I did not do `Firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` .
3. Then to get authcredential for google I run `var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
   googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);` (**I get an undefined googleUser error**) this error seems appropriate since I have not signed in using Google Oauth but thats what the 2nd steps states(not to signin)
4. And then this command to link with the current user who is on a Facebook Provider `auth.currentUser.link(credential)`

My understanding is that currentUser needs to be linked to my existing Provider(Facebook). It seems that credential variable for google is never computed. Anyone with a functional code example would really help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to manually link a google and email/pass account to existing facebook only firebase user, you can do the following:
First, the user should be signed in to Facebook.
Link the google user:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
auth.currentUser.linkWithPopup(provider);
```

Then link the email/pass account:

```
auth.currentUser.linkWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(auth.currentUser.email, 'password'))
```

All these accounts to be linked must be new and not already linked.

Comment: You mentioned manually, is there a different more automatic way of linking  providers?

Comment: Not exactly. I think I didn't explain that well. I meant manually as in the developer chooses to link based on some need (need google provider to access google calendar, upgrading an anonymous user, etc). The other case is when the backend server requires it for security reason. For example you sign to firebase using google which returns xyz@gmail.com. The user then signs in on a separate device using facebook which return the same email xyz@gmail.com. In that case an error is thrown that credential is already in use. You will need to link accounts in that case to link both providers.

Comment: @bojeil I see that you used `linkWithPopup()`. Then what is `linkWithCredential()` that's mentioned in the [Firebase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account)?

Comment: @bojeil Also, what if the user has **signed out** after signing in with Facebook, and then decided to sign in with Google? Can I link him with Google then?

Comment: linkWithCredential is used if you already have the oauth credential. The advantage here is that you don't need to open a popup or redirect. If you set "single account per email" in your project settings. If a user signs in with an email initially and then signs in with a OAuth provider that returns the same email, the backend will throw an error that the account exists. You will have to sign in to the first account and then link the OAuth provider account to it.

Comment: Google is a special case since a user with a google email is considered verified (google issued the account) and will overwrite the existing facebook account without requiring linking.

Comment: Instead of keeping separate accounts, can we merge the accounts if the users email is same?

Comment: I'm also interested in this case. Do we verify the email addresses first? I guess if the user signed up with Facebook using a phone number, we can't really merge the accounts automatically. We would need the user to do initiate this.

Comment: @bojeil sorry for asking all these question, I'm just implementing account linking at the moment and your answers come in in google search. So the question is, I'm trying to add in-app linking, however,  `linkWithPopup` & `linkWithRedirect` don't work in react-native it throws this error: "The operation is not supported in this environment", does firebase provide a manual way of doing this? Can't seem to find any information on it, Thanks

Comment: For react-native, you need to obtain the OAuth credential for the account you want to link, initialize and Firebase AuthCredential and then use `linkWithCredential` as popup/redirect operations are not support in that environment.

Comment: @bojeil thanks, I have the credential using `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)`, what object is this `linkWithCredential` method available on? `firebase.auth().linkWithCredential` is undefined

Comment: You link the credential to the current user: `firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessTok‌​en))`

Comment: Yes, just found it in some android docs, weirdly can't find it in js docs, Thanks.

Comment: @AlaaM. did you ever find a solution to linking with a user's credential when they're not already logged in with their original auth provider? I'm having trouble thinking of an intuitive UI to link someone's credential if they're not already logged in. For example if a user has a Google-based Firebase account and they click "Log in with Facebook" on my login page they will never be logged in to their Google account at that moment, so I won't have the ability to get data from Firebase.auth().currentUser. It's a dilemma

Comment: Also, current user with social provider like Facebook will be upgraded automatically to Apple when you made a re-login using Apple!  Since then you can no longer login with Facebook. To login with Facebook again you have to link it manually with your current user (Apple Credential).

Answer (score 2):

@bojeil I have read your question and  I found the way to log in both Google and Facebook logins having the same email account. First, in the Firebase, you need to allow

"Multiple accounts per email address"

[Allow multiple accounts per email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd2Cn.png)

Now you can log in with both Facebook having "xyz@gmail.com" & Google having the same email name as "xyz@gmail.com".But you will encounter the email as "null" for the second login having the same email. You can get over the null problem by using the below snippet.

Just use this snippet in on success task from the firebase:

Map profile = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile();

Object email = profile.get("email"); ///  Obtaining the email from the use though we use same email form facebook and Google log in accounts.

By this way, you can log in into both Facebook and Google logins using the same email.

I hope you got your doubt cleared with this info. Can you please get back to me if this suits your question?.

Thank you.

Comment: But this will create multiple firebase ID's for each provider - hence the name "multiple accounts". For devs who want to have ONE account per email address (no matter the provider) , DO NOT do this

Comment: If anyone wants to have the same email containing google and Facebook then this is the solution @MichaelBolboceanu

Comment: Completely agree with @MichaelBolboceanu.

Comment: This creates a mess in your database. Instead of having 1 email address linked to multiple providers, you end up having multiple entries of the same email address for every provider. So if a user signs in with google, facebook and twitter, using the same email, you end up having three separate entries in your database for that user.