# Combining Facebook and Google auth for Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication, google-authentication

**Background**

Hello, I'm new with Firebase for Android and I'm trying to implement the Facebook and Google auth/login for the first time. I followed these two tutorials for the corresponding authentication:

- http:// firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin
- http:// firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Separately, the `FacebookSignInActivity` and `GoogleSignInActivity` are working as they should.

**Problem**

The problem is that I'm trying to use the Google and Facebook auth in the same activity, but it won't work. Like so:

[image: result layout image]

**What I did**

I tried to keep the `FacebookSignInActivity` separate from the `GoogleSignInActivity` by letting them extend a `MainActivity` and set the layout in there.

But I think I'm supposed to merge the two into one. So I tried that but I'm getting a weird nullpointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener)' on a null object reference
```

I don't know why the object is null in the `onCreate` because I've copied the same code from the other two activities which are working:

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(user);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };
```

I'm not even sure if I'm even supposed to merge the two into one activity. I've also checked these links:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking
- [How to Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Firebase Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768529/how-to-link-multiple-auth-providers-to-an-firebase-account)

But it looks like that is something else from what I'm trying to do. If someone could help point me in the right direction, it would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted is not the code throwing the exception.  The exception occurs when you call `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener)` and `mAuth` is null.  Confirm that you have executed `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`, before trying to add the listener.

Comment: Like in the firebase tutorials, the line you are referring to: `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` is in my code snippet. It's being called in the onCreate. The `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);` is called in the onStart.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Facebook Login
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginButton mFacebookSignInButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
        mFacebookSignInButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_birthday", "user_friends");

        mFacebookSignInButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                firebaseAuthWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            }
        });

        // Google Sign-In
        // Assign fields
        Button mGoogleSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.google_button);

        // Set click listeners
        mGoogleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.google_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe anyone still looking for solution:

In Activity( yourLoginActivity.class)

*Create a constant int to represents the requestCode for ActivityForResult

```
   // You can change to any Value just be unique
   private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;
```

–> declare GoogleApiClient, FirebaseAuth, AuthStateListener and the CallbackManager

```
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
```

–> Initialize the variables declared above:

```
 mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();  mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
         FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
         if (user != null) {
             // User is signed in
             Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
         } else {
             // User is signed out
             Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
         }
     }  };
```

–> Get reference to SingInButton and LoginButton:

```
  LoginButton facebookLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_facebook_button);
  SignInButton mGoogleSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
```

–> Handle the SingInButton and LoginButton:

```
 facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_birthday");
 facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
         firebaseAuthWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken());
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancel() {
         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(FacebookException error) {
         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });

 mGoogleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         signIn();
     }
 });
```

–> Manage the GoogleSingInOptions and GoogleApiClient

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

–> Handle the Facebook Login

```
   private void authWithFacebook(AccessToken token) {
   Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
   final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    } else {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
}
```

–> Handle the Google Login:

```
  pprivate void authWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }else{
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
}
```

–> Override the onConnectionFailed():

```
 @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

–> Singing in and calling the onActivityForResult()

```
 private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

–> Implement GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

```
LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
....
 }
```

Be sure you have ***ENABLED FACEBOOK SDK*** Login FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE AND SET UP CORRECTLY!

Comment: your answer helped a lot bro. I've been scratching my head from last 2 days to do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody wanting to do this in Kotlin in a Fragment

```
class LoginFragment(): Fragment() ,  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private val TAG = "SignInActivity"
    private val RC_SIGN_IN = 9001
    private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var mAuthListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener? = null
    private var mCallbackManager: CallbackManager? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.likes_fragment, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(activity);
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

        google_container.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }

        // Facebook Button (LoginButton) from xml
        login_button.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
        login_button.fragment = this
        login_button.run {
            registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object:  FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Succesfull Facebook Sign In")
                    firebaseAuthWithFacebook(result?.accessToken!!)
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cancelled Facebook Sign In")
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Facebook sign in error : " + error.toString())
                }

            })
        }

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity!!.applicationContext)
            .enableAutoManage(this.activity!! /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build()

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mAuthListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
            val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.uid)
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out")
            }
        }
    }


    fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        mCallbackManager!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = result.signInAccount
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(token : GoogleSignInAccount) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleGoogleAccessToken:" + token);
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token.idToken,null)
        mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity as MainActivity, object : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {
                override fun onComplete(task: Task<AuthResult>) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    if(!task.isSuccessful){
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            })

    }


     private fun firebaseAuthWithFacebook(token : AccessToken) {
         Log.e(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
         val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
         mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
             .addOnCompleteListener(activity as MainActivity, object : OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {
                 override fun onComplete(task: Task<AuthResult>) {
                     Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                     if(!task.isSuccessful){
                         Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     }else{
                         Toast.makeText(activity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     }
                 }

             })

    }
}
```